# ASP:ListBox Get Selected Items - One Liner?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, listbox, c#-3.0

I am trying to get the selected items of an asp:ListBox control and put them in a comma delimited string. There has got to be a simpler way of doing this then:

```
foreach (ListItem listItem in lbAppGroup.Items)
{
    if (listItem.Selected == true)
    {
        Trace.Warn("Selected Item", listItem.Value);
    }
}
```

Is there a way to get this into one line? like my pseudo code here:

```
string values = myListBox.SelectedItems;
```

I am using ASP.NET and C# 3.5.

Thanks for any help!!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Using LINQ:

```
string values = String.Join(", ", lbAppGroup.Items.Cast<ListItem>()
                                                  .Where(i => i.Selected)
                                                  .Select(i => i.Value));
```

Comment: Hello, this is great. I am trying to get it to work and I get this problem:

'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItemCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Where' and no extension method 'Where' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItemCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I have LINQ in my using statement.

Comment: @user993514 I forgot the cast to `ListItem`, try that.

Comment: Perfect LINQ saves the day again. Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: What happened to  ListBox.getSelectedItems.. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa297606(v=vs.60).aspx

Comment: @Pleun actually after some investigation this is for WinForms not ASP.NET, good shout though.

Comment: Yes, my mistake. My development PC not here so I added the link too quickly. There is ListBox.GetSelectedIndices though. I thought it was getSelectedItems...

Comment: Great answer! Actually, the `.ToArray()` is not needed, since `String.Join` also takes an `IEnumerable` as second parameter. Source: [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421(v=vs.100).aspx)

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there is anything built in but you could do something like this:

```
  <asp:ListBox runat="server" ID="listBox" SelectionMode="Multiple">
    <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Text="text1" Value="value1"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Selected="false" Text="text2" Value="value2"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Text="text3" Value="value3"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Text="text4" Value="value4"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:ListBox>

    IEnumerable<string> selectedValues = from item in listBox.Items.Cast<ListItem>()
                                             where item.Selected
                                             select item.Text;

        string s = string.Join(",", selectedValues);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var selectedQuery = listBox.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Where(item => item.Selected); 
string selectedItems =  String.Join(",", selectedQuery).TrimEnd();
```

Comment: `.TrimEnd()` seems redundant here. If you want to remove whitespace from the string, you should IMHO do that operation in the first line, on each item.

Comment: first query does not retrieve a string

Answer (score 1):

Actually there IS something built in:

ListBox.getSelectedItems

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa297606(v=vs.60).aspx

Comment: Is this for Win Forms? I can't seem to get to that in ASP.NET

Comment: Yes, my mistake. My development PC not here so I added the link too quickly. There is ListBox.GetSelectedIndices though. I thought it was getSelectedItems...

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use the Request Form object which contains everything that was posted back. eg:

```
string values = Request.Form(lbAppGroup.UniqueID);  //returns "a,b" if they were selected
```

This by default returns a comma delimited list of selected items.
I sometimes use this way when I don't want or need to bind the data again but still want to get the selected values for processing.