# How to Check if ListBox is Empty on Client-Side

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I created a `javascript confirm` as below.

```
<script Type="Text/Javascript">

function CheckListBox(lvi)
{
    if(lvi == "")
    {
        if(confirm("Are you sure?"))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

</script>
```

I need to test if the `ListBox.Items` control is empty...  I already made reference on my aspx page

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/JS/confirm.js"></script>
```

I want to know how to call it on my `aspx.cs` page . . . So I can pass the `parameter`:

```
string oi = Listbox_Clubes.Items.Count.ToString();//Its the parameter I want to pass
```

Comment: Could you please, leave a comment telling me why the DownVote ?
It's easy downvote , but answer or leave a constructive comment isnt , ha ?

Comment: You can use this method: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.registerstartupscript.aspx) It run when your control are reload.

Comment: why the downvotes? i dont see what's wrong with this question. +1

Comment: I already use this, But I can't get a something like a confirm() to use the conditional `if/else` =\. Thanks anyway =)

Comment: @Thousand Well, "how do I run javascript code from an ASP codebehind" is a very common question, with lots of well documented answers.  This demonstrates no research effort, nor is it any harder than the examples that will be seen all over the place.

Comment: @Servy Ok, I explained myself wrong. Sorry ! And thanks for telling what was wrong.

Comment: @Ghaleon if you use `RegisterStartupScript` please add that so we can comment on if you're using it right.

Comment: @Destrictor I use `RegisterStartupScript` only for simple messages, because I cant get a ´Yes/No` from the user. So I need to know if it's possible to do what I asked above... If it's possible to work with the result of javascript on the codebehind, this case, `C#`.

Comment: When you figure out how to integrate with the server-side part (sorry, not my area), just `return confirm("Are you sure?")`. There's no need for the inner conditional.

Comment: If you want easy clientside communication, use [JQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/), more specifically [JQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/)

Comment: @Servy this isn't a case of needing to run javascript from code-behind... OP just has a bad title.

Comment: @MikeSmithDev The OP hasn't explained how his problem differs from every other "run javascript from codebehind" problem.  That lack of explanation makes it just as downvote worthy.

Comment: @Servy he did: "I need to test if the ListBox.Items control is empty"

Answer (score 0):

For your javascript, you can get the value without the code-behind (this assumes the script code is in the same page, in order to get the client ID):

```
 <script>
     function ClickListBox() {
         if ($("#<%= Listbox_Clubes.ClientID  %>").val() === null) {
             if (confirm("Are you sure?")) {
                 return true;
             }
             else {
                 return false;
             }
         }
     }
 </script>
```

Similarly, you don't use javascript to validate on the server side. The code you posted will return **all** items in the ListBox. Here is one way to get the count of the number of **selected** items (I'm using `.ToString()` based on the OP code example):

```
string oi = Listbox_Clubes.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Where(i => i.Selected).Count().ToString();
```

However, there is no reason why you would get this value and pass it back to the client-side to do validation (what it sounds like you want to do in your post). Mainly because this involves a post-back, and client-side validation, by its nature, should occur before post-back. Also, you will still need to do server-side validation, even when you have client-side validation.

Related: in the code-behind, you can test to see if anything is selected by:

```
bool hasValue = Listbox_Clubes.SelectedItem != null;
```

The `.SelectedItem` returns the selected item with the lowest index in the list control. When nothing is selected, this value is `null`... so you know if the value isn't `null`, then at least one item was selected.

If you want to require that they choose at least one item, you can use a [RequireFieldValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.requiredfieldvalidator.aspx) and let that handle both validations. If you haven't done much with ASP.NET validators, that would be one good thing to read up on.

It sounds like you probably should read more about client-side validation and server-side validation and how to use them... because it seems like you are mixing them up.

*The count code is a modified version of code in [ASP:ListBox Get Selected Items - One Liner?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8478992/asplistbox-get-selected-items-one-liner)*

Comment: Hello ! Thanks for answering me. But I don't want to select any value from ListBox, I just want to know if its empty or not ;S

Comment: Yes, that is what my `hasValue` boolean tells you. The other code doesn't tell you selected value either, it tells you how many items were selected.

Comment: @Ghaleon I think I see what you are trying to do. I updated my answer to show how to get the selected items via Javascript. This will not require a postback or code-behind. You may still need to run the code-behind logic if you need custom validation.

Comment: @Ghaleon did this help or not?

Comment: I did it in some other way, because i didnt understand how it works. Sorry about that and thanks for helping me out =-)

Answer (score 0):

See this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.registerstartupscript.aspx) for how to execute javascript from code behind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "CheckListBox(" + Listbox_Clubes.Items.Count.ToString() + ");", false);
}
```

Note: you must add a ScriptManager control in aspx page.

Comment: I see... Is possible to use this `ScriptManager` and PopUp kind of a `messagebox` with ´Yes/No` or `Yes/Cancel` ?

Comment: Yes, you can write any js code in RegisterStartupScript. In this case, show a confirm dialog.