# Selected Item - listbox insert to database

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, listbox, insert-into

I have a small problem associated with adding values ​​to database.

C# and SQL Server

I have this procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [AB].[AddMovie]
    @Actors nvarchar(255),
    @Director nvarchar(100),
    @Title nvarchar(255),
    @Year char(4),
    @Length nvarchar(5),
    @Description nvarchar(255),
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO AB.Movie (Title, Year, Lenght, Description, Actors, Director) 
    VALUES (@Title, @Year, @Lenght, @Description, @Actors, @Director)
END;
```

ADDCATEGORY_TYPE

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [AB].[AddCategoryType]
    @Category nvarchar(50),
    @Title nvarchar(255)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO AB.CategoryType (CategoryID, MovieID) 
    VALUES ((SELECT CategoryID 
             FROM ab.Category 
             WHERE name = @Category), 
            (SELECT Movie ID 
             FROM AB.Movie 
             WHERE Title = @Title));
END;
```

I load movie category via a table adapter:

```
private void LoadCategory()
{
    string kom = "";
    CinemaDataSetTableAdapters.LoadCategoryTableAdapter category = new CienamDataSetTableAdapters.LoadCategoryTableAdapter();
    category.Fill(cinemaDataSet.LoadCategory, ref kom);
}
```

into a listbox.

What am I trying to do?

I want to INSERT SELECTEDITEMS from listbox into the table (CategoryID FK, MovieID FK) but if I use in C#:

```
private void AddMovieButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        CinemaDataSetTableAdapters.QueriesTableAdapter tmp = new CinemaDataSetTableAdapters.QueriesTableAdapter();
        tmp.AddMovie(ActorsTextBox.Text, Director.TextBox.Text, TitleTextBox.Text, YearTextBox.Text, LenghtTextBox.Text, Description.TextBox.Text);

        List<string> list = new List<string>();

        foreach (var items in CategorylistBox.SelectedItems)
        {
            list.Add(items.ToString());
        }

        foreach (var items in list)
        {
            CinemaDataSetTableAdapters.QueriesTableAdapter kType = new CinemaDataSetTableAdapters.QueriesTableAdapter();
            kType.AddCategoryType((items), TitleTextBox.Text);
        }
    }
```

I get an error:

> Additional information: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'CategoryID', table 'JiPPZ507.AB.CategoryType'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

I was looking on the website, I found a lot of information, but it still does not work :/

I try too:

```
        List<string> selectedFields = CategorylistBox.SelectedItems.OfType<string>().ToList();
        foreach (var items in selectedFields)
        {

            string selectedItem = items.ToString();
            CinemaDataSetTableAdapters.QueriesTableAdapter kType = new CienamDataSetTableAdapters.QueriesTableAdapter();
            kType.AddCategoryType((selectedItem), TitleTextBox.Text);

        }
```

I don't get this:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'CategoryID', table 'JiPPZ507.AB.CategoryType'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails

but nothing add to table CategoryType in database  :(

Comment: So, is the CategoryId carrying a NULL? If you wish to have NULL allowed, change the DB model. Or else, you need to check why the code is sending NULL. Seeing the UI code might help.

Comment: OK, my all code is here:
[link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_aqF-0bbuILMlQ0V2ZyZENYLWc/view?usp=sharing)

I don't want NULL in table, 
but I can not figure out how to give value not NULL, and why it does not work. I tried two ways (You can see in code).

Comment: @Kangkan  did you could help me ? I'd appreciatev :)

Comment: I don't think you can get anything using CategorylistBox.SelectedItems. I presume you are using ASPX page. I was expecting the HTML part as well in the code link that you shared. You may use something like string values = String.Join(", ", lbAppGroup.Items.Cast<ListItem>()
                                                  .Where(i => i.Selected)
                                                  .Select(i => i.Value)); as in the post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8478992/asplistbox-get-selected-items-one-liner